# Split string with multiple length into array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of strings like this

```
A45618416541548234
A48432185120148084
A15973357048208202
```

I want to split these strings and put them into arrays like this

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
  (
   [0] => A45
   [1] => 6184165
   [2] => 41548234
  )
 [1] => Array
  (
   [0] => A48
   [1] => 4321851
   [2] => 20148084
  )
 [2] => Array
  (
   [0] => A15
   [1] => 9733570
   [2] => 48208202
  )
)
```

I want to split the strings into 3 parts - 1st to 3rd character, 4th to 10th, and 11th to 18th.
I tried doing this using substr, but I could make an array like above...
How can I accomplish this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$strings = array('A45618416541548234', 'A48432185120148084', 'A15973357048208202');

print_r(array_map(function ($v) {
                      return array(substr($v, 0, 3), substr($v, 3, 7), substr($v, 10, 8)); }
                , $strings));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
  (
   [0] => A45
   [1] => 6184165
   [2] => 41548234
  )
 [1] => Array
  (
   [0] => A48
   [1] => 4321851
   [2] => 20148084
  )
 [2] => Array
  (
   [0] => A15
   [1] => 9733570
   [2] => 48208202
  )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/onR0C)